Gnome Shell failed to load extensions after a black screen on Ubuntu 24.04.1
Since a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1, Gnome extensions disable themselves after a black screen (Energy Saving), including default Ubuntu extensions. When I leave the black screen, no icons or dock appear, just the wallpaper, a top bar with no menus, and the windows that were open before the black screen.
Everything works fine if I disable all extensions using the master switch on the top of the Extension Manager.
This issue doesn't append after a reboot or logging in a session.
What I've tried so far:

Disabled extensions one by one
Deleted outdated extensions in "~/.local/share/gnome-shell/"
Removed all my extensions (except the Ubuntu ones)
Tried to install extensions with extensions.gnome.org

The problem persists if the extension switch is set to ON after a black screen. Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 24.04.1
nvidia-driver-550
Wayland, but the problem appends with org too
GNOME Shell 46.0
Gnome Tweak Tools and Gnome Extentions Manager


Same problem here, but I don't have any additional phantom display.

I finally found the solution! 
For some reason, during the fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04.1, a phantom display was created, labelled "Unknown 13.3"". You can see it in Settings > Displays. I disabled this phantom display, and now everything works perfectly.
It seems I'm not the only one who encountered this issue:

How do I disable/get rid of PRIME (None-1-1) display?
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1ck2ygc/weird_second_display_nvidia_prime_display/
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2085880

There are ways to edit config files to permanently remove the phantom display, but for now, I'm just happy that disabling it worked and don't want to risk messing things up again.
